# Error trying to push a build to a first gen iPod running os 3.1.3 using SDK 4

Tags: device, ios4

I just upgraded to iPhone SDK 4, I was building to the iPod running OS 3.1.3 fine untill i ugraded the SDK. When I try to build now I get the following error:

Can't run 'AppName' - was built for 'armv7', but device requires 'armv6' or compatible architecture.

In the project settings I have set the Architectures to Standard (armv7 armv6), and set the Base SDK to iPhone Device 4.0. I also set the iPhone OS Deployment Target to iPhone OS 3.1.3.

Any ideas what might be going wrong on me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I changed the project settings but also had to change the active target settings.
This is done in Project -> Edit Active Target "appName". I just had to switch the Architecture from optimised to standard.

Comment: Just updated to Xcode 3.2.3 and SDK 4.0.1 and had similar problem building to a second generation iPod touch. I never would have thought to check the target build settings. Thanks!